# Datatables update single column every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, asynchronous, datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) to show several information and button.
This is the javascript used to initialize the datatables

```
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#datatableTable' ) ) {
        datatableTable = $('#datatableTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            columnDefs: [
                         { "width": "25%", "targets": 4},
                         {
                             targets: [4,5,6],
                             //set priority to column, so when resize the browser window this botton stay on the screen because have max priority
                             visible: (document.getElementById('role').value == '[ROLE_ADMIN]' || document.getElementById('role').value == '[ROLE_FLEET_ENG]'
                                 || document.getElementById('role').value == '[ROLE_SUPPLIER]'),
                             responsivePriority: 1,
                             orderable: false,
                             searchable: false,
                         },
                         ...
                         ],
                         //fix problem with responsive table
                         "autoWidth": false,
                         "ajax":{ 
                             "url":  "datatable/" + $("#selectedCar").val(),
                             "dataSrc": ...
                                     return json.result.data;                                               
                             }, 
                             "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                                 window.location.href = "/DART/500";
                             }
                         },
                         "columns": [
                                    ....
                                     {data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                                         var datId="deleteDat"+row.idAcquisition;
                                         if (row.datUploaded){  
                                             return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="deleteDat" target="'+row.idAcquisition+'" id="'+datId+'" data-toggle="modal"'
                                             +'data-target="#deleteDatModal">Delete</button>'
                                         }else 
                                             return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="deleteDat" target="'+row.idAcquisition+'" id="'+datId+'" data-toggle="modal"'
                                             +'data-target="#deleteDatModal" disabled>Delete</button>'                                          
                                     },
                                     ],
                                     "fnDrawCallback": function(data, type, row, meta ) {
                                         //Initialize checkbox for enable/disable user
                                         $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch({size: "small", onColor:"success", offColor:"danger"});
                                     },
        });
    }
    else {
        datatableTable.ajax.url("datatable/" + $("#selectedCar").val()).load();
    }
```

Column 5 (starting from 0) has buttons, each button may be disabled or enabled depends on the `datUploaded` boolean value.
This variable change if user load file ,but this value has setted after async task, so I don't know in my javascript when this task end.

I thought to update every 5 seconds only this column, but how can I do it?
I find `datatableTable.column(5).cells().invalidate().render()` but I receive an error (unknow parameter "isShow" for row 0) and update doesn't work.
Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Could you please strip down your example code to the actual problematic part(s)

Comment: Now is better? I think the problem is both "fnDrawCallback" and instructions to update the column

Comment: you say "setted after async task, so I don't know in my javascript when this task end", but you can pass .load() a callback to be executed after the ajax call has terminated, so you can actually know when the task is over

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, you can pass .load() a callback function that will be called automatically when the ajax request is complete. In this callback you can update your table as you prefer. After you update the table, remember to call `datatableTable.draw();` to apply the changes.

I don't think invalidate() and render() are necessary.

So your `else` branch would be something like

```
datatableTable.ajax.url("datatable/" + $("#selectedCar").val()).load(function() {
    /*
    ...do something to the table...
    */

    datatableTable.draw();
});
```

Comment: async task (Spring) is on the server, I should call datatable.draw() every 5 seconds? I would like to update only that column and not all table otherwise I may use datatableTable.ajax.reload();

Comment: Sorry i gave from granted you were referring to the ajax call. Yes if the task is executed in parallel on the server independently of the script then you need to poll the server for the results. Do you have an url you can call to get the updated information?

Comment: I have url for all the table, the update is datUploaded to true or false. I can't update all the table because user may load information or make other operations